# Avoid reload ads while switch from one activity to another

Tags: android

my problem is when i switch one activity to another activity then admob take time to load,so i want it should load only once on every screen,so let me know how it possible if it possible then how to store ads in database or sharepreference or other way,please help me
 my code is

```
adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addd);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();



adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a Boolean value:

```
public class AdsClass extends Activity {

    private Boolean adLoaded;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // When activity is created by first time adLoaded = false
        // After activity is created, onResume() method loads
        adLoaded = false;


    }
    @Override

    // onResume() is loaded after onCreate -> onStart(); and when activity is resumed

    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        // On creation, ad is loaded and while app keeps running (even in background) ad will not load anymore
        // until you stop the app

        if (adLoaded) {

            Log.e("Ad", "Skipping");

        }else {

            loadAdvertisement();
        }

    }

    public void loadAdvertisement() {

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addd);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adLoaded = true;

    }
}
```

If you don't want load the ads even changing activities you need to use an Intent Extra in every activity change:

`Send Extra`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras("adLoadedInAdsClass", adLoaded);
```

`Receive Extra in other activity`

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Boolean adLoaded = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("adLoadedInAdsClass");
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I forget something. Try the new code from my answer.

Comment: if adLoaded will true then from where ad will come? after switch the activity

Comment: I have edited my code, When activity is loaded by first time ad is loaded and boolean value of adLoaded changes to `true`. If you don't want load the ad in one activity anymore even moving between activities you need to use Intent.putExtra and implement the code of adLoaded in every activity changing the Boolean name which is passed between activities in putExtra according to your activites names.

Comment: i want ad run continuously,even activity changed,it should run continuously,according to your logic,when i switched activity then adLoaded gets true,and when i come back on same activity then its not loading admob

Comment: Ok. let me know if you have further problems